# Unable to delete list items

Tags: infopath, custom-list

I am not able to delete the list items. The form was created using Infopath and I don't know how to solve this issue.

Please see the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Check log files. It seems your list has some issues.

Comment: How to access the log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the field name is same as internal name? Title field is always same, no matter external or internal but other fields, especially the ones with the spaces between them, are different. Best way (for debugging) is to remove all fields and add 2-3 fields at a time and then run your code but to avoid wasting time, i would suggest check the internal names of all the fields that you are using in your code. I am sure using the correct internal names will solve your problem

To get the Internal name we can also go to ListSettings, click on the column and check the URL for the value of 'Field'

Comment: The form had around 200 fields in it and I'm not sure which caused these errors.

Comment: you can use this utility to find the internal names of the field and then check with your code. http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.de/2012/10/sharepointfinding-column-display-and.html

Comment: It is all the same.